# Is there any evidence to support Dayananda Saraswati's unorthodox claim that the medieval Sri Vaishnava scholar Yamunacharya was a Muslim?

Tags: history, dayananda-saraswati, arya-samaj, yamunacharya

Hindu-reformist [Dayananda Saraswati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dayananda_Saraswati) claimed that the medieval Sri Vaishnava scholar [Yamunacharya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamunacharya) was a Greek or Muslim who was originally called "Yavanacharya".

From *[Life of Dayanand Saraswati](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.275281/2015.275281.Life-Of_djvu.txt)*:

> Its founder was Shatakopa, 
>   bom in a Kanjar(low caste) family. Later, Munibanan, a 
>   bom sweeper, **and then Yavanacharya, a Greek or a Muslim, 
>   taught it.**
>
> ...
>
> It was known as the Bhagwat faith. It also became known 
>   as Pancaratra.* It was monotheism and it taught that 
>   salvation is the result of Bhakti or devotion. Later, this 
>   Bhagwat religion became transformed into Vaishnavism. 
>   **Its first teacher of note was Yavanacharya later called 
>   Yamunacharya.** Another teacher Kathu Muni preceded 
>   Yavanacharya. The later was a disciple of the Alvars of 
>   the Deccan. He arranged their hymns. Yavanacharya 
>   defended the Vaishnava faith against attacks upon it and 
>   wrote several books.

Is there any evidence to support his claim?

Comment: So mud slinging had reached that level at that point of time. :-(

Comment: Claim is too absurd.

Comment: @Ikshvaku: I don't think Swami Dayanand's views are heretical.  As far as I understood, he tried his best to revive what he thought to be pure Vedic approach.  He did not approve the Puranic way of viewing the God.  Anyways, he is a part of history now and it does not augur well in digging his writings/sayings made a century back.  Many people might be looking towards the Veda now a days for guidance but not his way of approach to the Veda.